# How to scale data to display a time series plot using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, time-series, data-visualization

I made a visualization. It shows the size of many types of files in GB. what can I use to scale it? 
In the plot I can only see 3 "file_name". But the legend dhows more than 3.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'file_type': ['file'] * 1 +  ['file.png'] * 1 +  ['file.PNG'] * 1 + ['file.csv'] * 2,
    'size': [11] * 5,
    'created_at': ['2020-01-01 23:00:34'] *1 + ['2020-02-01 23:00:34'] * 2 + ['2020-03-01 23:00:34']*1 + ['2019-01-02 23:00:34']})

df['created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_at']).dt.normalize()
group1= df['file_type'].str.lower().str.extract(r'(\.\w+$)', expand=False).fillna('unknown')
group2 = df['created_at'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')

df_new=df.groupby([group1, group2])['size'].sum().div(1000000000).round(3).unstack(level=0)
df_new.plot(subplots=False, figsize=(10, 8))
```

[image]

EDIT
I added the suggestions given. Plot looks like this now:

[image]

Comment: you have a lot of NaNs in your df_new. NaNs are not shown in the line plot, only lines between non-NaNs. So you may want to try `df_new.plot(style='+-', subplots=False, figsize=(10, 8))`

Comment: and / or convert the NaNs to zeros: `df_new.fillna(0).plot(...`

Comment: try log scale: `df_new.plot(subplots=False, figsize=(10,8), logy=True)`.

Comment: @Stef there are many NaN because during those periods no one was using those file_type. If I turn them to 0, will it change the meaning of the plot? I am not sure.

Comment: it depends on what exactly you want to show with the chart: if no-one created a file the sum of bytes of files created at this date is 0. It only plays a role if you want to differentiate between "no files were created" and "one or more empty files were created"

Comment: if you're interested in the amount of space used up by files created at that date and want to show how this breaks up into individual file types, then maybe a stacked bar chart is a better option.